# How to handle multiple Tridion fields in a GUI extension?

Tags: 2011, cme, gui-extensions

We have the ability to add, remove, and re-order items in a field per [SDL Live Content](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_34A7EEA7E40649E79052454C70ED3431)([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)).

**Is there a way to get access to multiple fields in a component form from the same Custom URL pop-up?**

**Edit**: removed alternative ideas to make question clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a similar approach as the one used in the Items Selector available in Tridion World http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/itemselector.aspx

1) You will need to register your custom URL popup as a View.

```
try {
    var op = window.opener;
    if (op && op.Tridion && op.Tridion.Controls && op.Tridion.Controls.Popup) {
        op.Tridion.Controls.Popup.registerView(null, window);
    }
}
catch (e) {
}
```

2) Access to the Windows.Opener (Component View) fields.

```
var args = window.dialogArguments;
    if (args) {
        // get current field value
        var value = "";
        var fields = args.getFields();
        if (fields && fields.length > 0) {
            var values = fields[0].getValues();
            if (values && values.length > 0) {
                value = values[0]
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I just mentioned the Item Selector as an example for another question. :-) So this approach would simplify the setup by having the same extension (custom page/pop-up) handle various parameters. We just need to pass these parameters via the query string in each field's custom url (it'd be a small initial setup).